# Objective-C: Programmatically created UIPickerView not showing anything, but IBOutlet works

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

I am creating a `UIPickerView` with pure code and I am dropping the `UIPickerView` as a subView in the `ContentView` of `CXAlertView`(https://github.com/ChrisXu1221/CXAlertView). 

I've configured the `datasource` and `delegate` but when I run it, nothing shows in the `AlertView's` `ContentView`, in which `NSLog` returns my component's number as 1.
Strange thing here is that when I link the `pickerview` as an `IBOutlet`, everything works.
Please Help. 
(PS:Please ignore the instances in my code, they are all working)

`HJCouponViewController.m`

```
#import "HJCouponViewController.h"
#import "CXAlertView.h"
@interface HJCouponViewController()<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> {
 NSArray *largeArray;
 NSArray *smallArray;  
 }
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIPickerView *prizePicker;

@end

@implementation 

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [self.prizePicker setDelegate:self];
    [self.prizePicker setDataSource:self];
}
- (IBAction)addPicker:(id)sender {
     CXAlertView *pickerAlert = [[CXAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Select one" message:@"Choose From Below" cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [pickerAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"Select" type:CXAlertViewButtonTypeDefault handler:^(CXAlertView *alertview, CXAlertButtonItem *button){

}];
    [pickerAlert setContentView:[self prizePickerContent]];
    [self.prizePicker reloadAllComponents];

    [pickerAlert show];
    NSLog(@"%d",prizePicker.numberOfComponents);

}
#pragma mark - Pickerview Datasource
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
return 2;
}
-(CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component{
if (component == 0) {
    return 80;
}
 return 160;
}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger)component{
    if (component == 0) {
        return 3;
    }
if (component == 1) {
    NSInteger index = [prizePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            return smallArray.count;
            break;
        case 2:
            return largeArray.count;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
    return 0;
}

-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
if (component == 0) {
    NSArray *leftComponentNameArray = @[@"Favourite",@"Small Prizes",@"Large Prizes"];
    return [leftComponentNameArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
if (component == 1) {
    NSInteger index = [prizePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return @"Not Set yet";
            break;
        case 1:{
            HJInstance *smallInstance = [smallArray objectAtIndex:row];
            return smallInstance.Name;

            break;
        }

        case 2:{
            HJInstance *largeInstance = [largeArray objectAtIndex:row];
            return largeInstance.Name;
        }


            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
return nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Check whether you are setting `delegate` to picker.

Answer (score 0):

I miss a line where you add the picker to the hierarchy of views:

```
[self.view addSubview:pickerAlert];
```

Comment: I am adding the UIPickerView to the ContentView of CXAlertView, not the view of ViewController. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
```

needs to be

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
```

(lower case 'v')

Comment: Sorry it was just typed error, not much difference is made

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @SergeyKuryanov is that directed at me or Zhang Jackie? My answer gives a reason for an uncalled 'viewDidLoad' method.